# Can a single function pointer point to multiple classes member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, class-members, member-pointers

Here are the requirements posed by my application. I have a class A, that accepts a function pointer say cFunc, Basically in my implementation of A, I have it call cFunc multiple times.

The cFunc pointer itself should point to different functions depending upon the application. Thus for each application I create a class with the same function definition as cFunc, however I cannot assign the class's member function to this pointer

```
class A {
    typedef double (*Def_CFunc)(std::vector<double>);
    A(Def_CFunc _cFunc) { // Some implementation}
    // Other Functions
};

class B { double someFunc(std::vector<double> b); };
class C { double someOtherFunc(std::vector<double> a); };

int main () {
    B firstObj;
    C secondObj;

    // Depending upon the situation, I want to select class B or C
    double (*funcPointer)(std::vector<double>) = firstObj.someFunc; // Error in this line of code

    A finalObj(funcPointer);
}
```

So how do I make it such that any class with a member function of the given format can be used to initialize the class A?

Comment: Do you really need the functions to be member functions?

Comment: Not really, But the functions will be very tightly integrated with the class variable, so that seems to be the best way to go..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly your requirements are, but it looks like you want an [interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_%28object-oriented_programming%29) (or abstract base class in C++ lingo).

If both `B` and `C` inherit from a common base class, you can pass a pointer to this base class and invoke functions on it:

```
class I { virtual double func(std::vector<double> a) = 0; }
class B : public I { double func(std::vector<double> a); };
class C : public I { double func(std::vector<double> a); };
```

You can pass an `I*` pointer to `A` and just use `i->func`.

Comment: I have to disagree with you. Sometimes you need just static polymorphism.

Comment: @innochenti: That is as good as using global functions. I only suggested interfaces because the OP was going the object-oriented way.

Answer (score 1):

[Pointer to member function](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) has different syntax than pointer to ordinary function and can only point to a method of one given class. To be able to point to methods in different classes use [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/function.html) or if C++11 is available use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). These can hold any method or function of a given signature.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `std::function` together with either `std::bind` or lambda expressions (or the Boost equivalent of the first two), because member function pointers don't allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using std::bind + std::function. Lets write some template class wrapper, that takes any static type as input. Then use this wrapper in free function switch_obj. Usage is very simple.

```
typedef std::function<double(std::vector<double>)> my_foo;

template<class C>
struct switcher
{
    static my_foo convert(C* obj)
    {
        return my_foo( std::bind(&C::someFunc,obj,std::placeholders::_1) );
    }
};

template<class T>
my_foo switch_obj(T* obj)
{
    return switcher<T>::convert(obj);
}

void main()
{
    B firstObj;
    C secondObj;

    auto f =  switch_obj(&firstObj);
    A a(f);
}
```